# How to use CPackDeb?

Tags: cmake, cpack

What do I miss in using CPackDeb? (cmake version 3.5.1)

For example, if I want to find out `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE`, an empty string is returned. If I clone the respective code, everything works as expected. Also, other
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPackDeb.html specific variables seem to not work, and also my KDevelop does not highlight them.

Since using `include(CPackDeb)` results in error message `CPackDeb.cmake may only be used by CPack internally`, I presume there is some other way (a missed parameter?) to activate it.

Comment: It is you (as a **package author**) who should **set** `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE` and other DEB generator-specific variables listed [in docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPackDeb.html). Some of these variables has default value, which is used if no value is provided. But these values are not preset when you call `include(CPack)`.

Comment: The docs contains "Default : Output of dpkg –print-architecture (or i386 if dpkg is not found)" and really, this is present in the code. When I rely on that default, it is just an empty string.

Comment: Again, this is a default value which is **used** (internally) by the DEB generator, but it is **not presented** for user. As for the code, line [CPackDeb.cmake:728](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CPackDeb.cmake#L728): `elseif(NOT CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE)` clearly tells the same: variable is set to default value **only if it is not set** (by the user) previously.

Comment: This is what does not happen: if I just use `set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-Linux-${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE}")`, without defining it, relying to the default value that shuld be set by CPackDeb, `${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE}` is an empty string.

Comment: Once again: You **cannot extract default value** from `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE`: this value is set *after* your code is executed. If you want value returned by `dpkg –print-architecture`, you may obtain it manually, with `execute_process` command.

Comment: It looks like I misunderstood the purpose. My guess was, that this value will be part of the package name. What other purpose is this variable used for by CMake?

Comment: `My guess was, that this value will be part of the package name.`, according to the code, this is true if you set variable `CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME` to "DEB-DEFAULT".